# CSS drop down menu in 960 grid system

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, 960.gs

I'm building a website based on 960 grid system ([www.960.gs](http://www.960.gs)),
and I've encountered a problem.
I want to put drop down menu but with no success. I tried many tutorials
but i only got more confused.
Is there a way to create a menu for this kind of website?
this is the website by the way:
[My website](http://3pon.co.il/test/1/index.html)

Thank you for you help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to do this by using just CSS is by using absolute positioning on the contents of your drop-down, and have another unordered list inside each li that needs drop-downs.

So the markup looks like this:

```
<ul id="nav">
    <li><a>Nav Item with dropdown</a>
        <ul id="dropDown">
            <li><a>Dropdown Menu Item</a></li>
            <li><a>Dropdown Menu Item</a></li>
            <li><a>Dropdown Menu Item</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

You will then set #nav li (or #nav li a) to position:relative; and have the #nav li ul set to position:absolute; with it's position off the side of the screen using left:-9999px;

Then set the hover of the element you set to position relative (li or li a), while including the child ul:

```
#nav li:hover ul {
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
}
```

This way, on hover, the child element will come into focus underneath the parent menu item.

See it working [here](http://jsfiddle.net/KempfCreative/D4RLa/17/).

Comment: Thank you i found my mistake. I closed the first <li> before I put the sub menu. 
What do i need to do so it will appear under the purple bar?

Comment: I don't want to give you too much info because half of learning is figuring it out as you go. That being said, you could try messing around with either the positioning of the absolute element, or playing around with the padding and margin of the relative element. Good luck!

Comment: I'm on a deadline with this one and I'm very rusty at this, but I sincerely appreciate your comment. I'll do my best to learn. Thank you for your help =]